# Which is drain perimeter for PMOS and NMOS in this layout?

Tags: layout

The following is the picture for the layout.

[image]

The book said PD for NMOS is  \$15\lambda\$ while  \$19\lambda\$ for PMOS.  I am new to layout of CMOS. The red circle I have drawn is the one I think is drain. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have successfully identified the drain. However, the red box does not properly define the perimeter term. The perimeter of the drain is found by tracing the geometry of the active diffusion not touching the gate. Below, you can see what gets counted towards the drain perimeter.

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your work. I am still not sure about your nmos. Why do you put two \$1\lambda\$ for nmos ?

Comment: @kile Look at the perimeter of the active shape under the contact. It looks like the minimum contact is 4λ square, but the transistor is drawn with a width of 3λ. The perimeter of the drain active region follows the yellow line, where each of those short segments is 1λ. This is basically a "dogbone" transistor layout, where the width is narrower than the minimum contact width. The stipple pattern makes it hard to see without colors, but I'm assuming active is enclosed by the yellow line I drew.

Comment: The other thing, to be a bit more precise, is that you have boxed in red the drain *contact*, which is not the entire drain. If your question was "did I select between the source and drain correctly?", the red box is sufficient to me. However, if you meant "did I enclose the entire drain area?", you did not (it extends to the gate).

Comment: I understand the upper \$1\lambda\$, but the lower  \$1\lambda\$ is not easy to understand. According to the one you draw, the total perimeter is \$1\lambda + 4\lambda + 4\lambda + 5\lambda = 14\lambda\$

Comment: @kile The NFET drain perimeter that I draw is 15λ. I tried to update the image to show the lines that contribute to the drain perimeter parameter, and the estimated dimensions. Do you have a version of this design with color instead of black and white stipple? That would probably be easier to see the active area.

Comment: Thank you for kindly reply. Unfortunately, it's a picture form the book (https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Integrated-Circuits-2nd-Rabaey/dp/0130909963) so I don't have thedesign with colour. But your updated picture really helps!

Answer (score 0):

The drain of the NMOS will be connected to ground the circuit will look something like this:

[image]
Source: https://www.allaboutelectronics.org/cmos-logic-gates-explained/

Vdd may not be 5V as shown in the image.

Comment: Can you have a look at the layout? which part is drain in the layout? How does the author of the book knows the \$15\lambda\$ for drain perimeter?

Comment: With symmetric devices, the drain is usually connected to the output of a stage. These devices appear to have abutted well/substrate contacts for the source, so they are not symmetric devices.